# Binding not updating property of a collection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DataGrid that's bound to a `ObservableCollection<MyModel>` `MyModel` has a boolean property IsSelected that's bound to a checkbox on the view. But clicking on the checkbox doesn't update MyModel.IsSelected value. I know my binding is correct because if I assign `true` to IsSelected from the viewModel I can see the checkbox checked. But it doesn't change IsSelected value when I click on checkbox.

Here's my view:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding HomeTeamAthletes}"
              MinHeight="200" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="30">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here's my ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> HomeTeamAthletes =>
        new ObservableCollection<MyModel>
        {
            new MyModel(),
            new MyModel(),
            new MyModel(),
            new MyModel(),
            new MyModel(),
        };

    public class MyModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private bool _isSelected;

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get => _isSelected;
            set { Set(ref _isSelected, value); }
        }

        public MyModel()
        {
            IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does it help if you use `Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`?

Comment: @ASh do you have any idea why that is necessary? if you use do the same thing that he does in an ItemTemplate, the updatesourcetrigger is LostFocus, but if you use it inside a CellTemplate of a DataGridTemplateColumn, apparently it suddendly changes to Explicit.

Comment: @ASh yah it actually does. It's stupid you need to do that :/ feel free to post it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems CheckBox.IsChecked binding doesn't propagate value to bound source immediately. To change that set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: Is Mode=TwoWay actually required?

Comment: I don't think so, it just repeats the default setting

Comment: @Clemens it's not required. It was my last try to fix the problem. Didn't think of UpdateSourceTrigger